# how to make chrome re-render an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe

Can anyone suggest any code specific to Chrome to force it to re-render an iframe?  We are seeing this really strange phenomenon where intermittently, the iframe we load on the page will be all white.  When you move your mouse, you can even see the title tags of the underlying elements.  As soon as you try to inspect it in the debugger, it instantly fixes itself.  It also fixes itself when you resize the page/iframe.  We haven't been able to come up with a way to detect programmatically when this is happening though b/c it just seems to be a weird bug with Chrome not rendering it.  Is there code specific to chrome to tell it to do a re-render cycle? (a simple jquery show/hide doesn't affect it)  Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

[image: you can still see the title tags on hover and access the dom elements via javascript]

Answer (score 1):

In chrome, the code for reloading an iframe is (using pure JavaScript):

1. `document.getElementById('iframeID').location.reload();`
2. `document.getElementById('iframeid').src += '';`

The first method reloads the iframe by calling that `reload()` method, the second method reloads the iframe by appending an empty string, which forces the iframe to reload.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but changing the url of the iframe  actually seems to trigger the problem b/c if we resize the browser to fix the issue, it reoccurs when the user navigates to a new url within the iframe.

Comment: @jessieloo In that case, you could try option 1

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to force the iframe's CSS to redraw. One trick is to read the height

`document.getElementById("yourIframe").contentDocument.documentElement.offsetHeight`